# Weird behavior release APK ionic

Tags: android, debugging, ionic-framework, httpclient, release

The problem is when I generate the APK in release mode, the login in my app doesn’t work. But… I already done a lot of tests. And I found that the problem is when I change “Debuggable” to false. If I set it true, the app works like a charm.

The other problem is that I can’t upload a debuggable APK to Google Play.

[image]

Comment: Why this question is tag with "ionic-framework". is the app created using ionic ?

Comment: Yes, the ionic project can be opened in Android studio, to build, run, debug. When you add cordova Android platform

Answer (score 0):

You dont need android studio in ionic projects.
check **https://ionicframework.com/docs/intro/deploying/**

Comment: Of course I don't. I tried everything. I always use this commands, same result. That's why I'm trying to use Android studio, for an advanced configuration in the APK

Comment: well, maybe this is your problem: when you build an ionic app with --release , you can't use it before signting it (in case you didnt)

Answer (score 0):

No need of Studio for building Ionic Apps.

Just go with the following commands

```
// For Debug build
ionic cordova build android

// For Release builds
ionic cordova build android --release

//For Production builds
ionic cordova build android --prod --release
```

Comment: Of course I don't. I tried everything. I always use this commands, same result. That's why I'm trying to use Android studio, for an advanced configuration in the APK

Comment: Then you need to check your app logic for Logic. Can you be more specific on that. Also is your Login code shareable ?